# Arduino skips case inside the switch

Tags: arduino, switch-statement, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

### Whenever counter_1 gets the value of 4, Arduino automatically changes that to 1 and so skips the 4th case.

How can I solve this problem?
I m trying to clone time settings of Casio F-91W.
Whenever I push the button, the counter will increase and goes to one left digit that we will change(in this method digits will only blink).
I set 4 case:

1. Second digit blink
2. Minute digit blink
3. Hour digit blink
4. No blink

```cpp
void updateCounter_1() {
    counter_1 = counter_1 + 1;
    if (counter_1 == 5) {
        counter_1 = 1;
    }
}

void settTime(){

    switch (counter_1) {
    case 1:
        lcd.setCursor(6, 1);
        lcd.print("  ");
        delay(150);
        updateHrs();
        updateMins();
        printSecs();
        delay(150);
        break;

    case 2:
        lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
        lcd.print("  ");
        delay(150);
        printMins();
        delay(150);
        break;

    case 3:
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("  ");
        delay(150);
        printHrs();
        delay(150);
        break;

    case 4:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of setting `counter_1` and doing the `if`, try this: `counter_1 = (cointer_1 + 1 % 4)` .

Answer (score 1):

> Whenever counter_1 gets the value of 4, Arduino automatically changes that to 1 and so skips the 4th case.

That's not quite right, at least, not based on the code you've shown us.

When `counter_1` is 4, the switch goes to case 4, but that case doesn't do anything.  The next time to counter is updated, it's reset to 4.

Note that cases 1 through 3 have some delays, but case 4 doesn't, so it may seem like case 4 doesn't happen.  But it does, it's just much faster than the others.